# One view over another view: top view should handle SOME MotionEvents

Tags: android, android-view, motionevent

I have two views. One of them (`bottom view`) already handling scrolling, pinch-to-zoom, double tap and other actions. The second one (which lays over this one; let's call it `top view`) is my custom view. For example I want `top view` to handle long press action. The issue is that to achive this I need my `top view` to receive `ACTION_DOWN` and some `ACTION_MOVE` events. So I override `onTouch` method and return `true` when `ACTION_DOWN` received. This causes my `bottom view` to not receive any events. According to documentation it's ok but how can I achieve my goal in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I used FrameLayout to display text over image.On click of text I showed one text and on click of image I showed another different Toast.It is working fine.Here's my code

```
<FrameLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:background="#D6FFD6"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <ImageView 
                 android:id="@+id/img"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
       <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt"
                  android:text="learnandroideasily.blogspot.com"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#003399"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"/>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is not what I need. You example is rather obvioгs. Your views handle separate actions (click on ImageView and click on TextView) while mine must handle some actions  
simultaneously.

Comment: I didn't got what exactly you want to do?Please elaborate.thnx